# Символьный массив и строки

Tags: c

**Вводится** вручную символьный массив типа char. Нужно потом сделать проверку каждого элемента равен он 1 или 0, если хотя бы один из элементов массива не является 0 или 1, то вывести Number is wrong.

Мой код выглядит примерно так, не могу понять в чём ошибка:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char str[10] = {0};
    scanf("%s", str);
    for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        if(str[i] != 0 && str[i] != 1)
            printf("Number is wrong");
    }
        system("pause");
         return(0);
}
```

Comment: Что имеется в виду под 1 и 0? `1` и `0`? Или `'1'` и `'0'`? Это совершенно разные вещи.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы сравниваете символ с числом. Нужно сравнивать символ с символом:

```
if (str[i] != '0' && str[i] != '1')
```

Кроме того, не ясно почему вы выбрали в качестве размера строки 6. Используйте функцию `strlen()`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < strlen(str); ++i)
```

Comment: Да, действительно. Глупая ошибка с моей стороны, я исправил и всё получилось. Спасибо большое! А может еще подскажете как можно сделать вывод каждого элемента по отдельности ?

Comment: @David, с помощью цикла. В примере проход и проверка каждого символа, а вам нужно выводить его на экран. `for (int i = 0; i < strlen(str); ++i) printf("%c", str[i]);`